# Spring multithreading

Tags: spring, multithreading

I have a question regarding the thread-safety. For example: I have RestController with two endpoints :

```java
@RestController
class MyController {

    @Autowired
    MyService service;

    @GetMapping
    public void add(int i) {
        service.add(i);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public void delete(int i) {
        service.delete(i);
    }
}

@Component
class MyService {
    
    private List<Integer> list;
    
    public void add(int i) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    public void delete(int i) {
        list.remove(i);
    }
}
```

As I understand, because MyService has scope singleton, his local variable list will share between threads and not thread-safety? If yes, what are the best practices to resolve this issue?

Comment: Correct, your code is not thread-safe. The answer to how to solve this, though, is complicated. It depends. You can try and use a thread-safe data structure, like [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), or use proper synchronization with `synchronized` and/or locks. For more information on this, you'll need to study multi-threading in Java a little. The book Java Concurrency in Practice is the go-to book on the topic.

Comment: What is the best practice? For example, I have one collection and one let's say Util class. Collection i can do thread-safe and Utils object define with bean scope request?

Comment: The easiest correct thing you can do _with your current code_ is to declare the methods `add()` and `delete()` as `synchronized` in your service. However, this is not something you would actually do in practice because of multiple reasons, and the actual solution depends on the required concurrency. In general, the rule of thumb is that all accesses to `list` must be synchronized in some way.

Comment: The most common approach, *I think*, is using a lock from the [`java.util.concurrent.locks`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html), most likely the `ReentrantReadWriteLock` (though `StampedLock` performs better if it can be used), or simply adding `synchronized { ... }` blocks in your `add()` and `delete()` methods. Most of the approaches limit concurrency in some way, though, so a informed decision needs to be taken. For simple solutions, the above will correctly work, though.

Comment: you can use ConcurrentLinkedQueue here instead of List

Comment: Resolve the problem with the collection it isn't a problem. What about Utils? As i see the solution is to define the bean with scope request. Is it correct?

Comment: Oh, one more thing! The code `list.remove(i)` calls a [different method than you think](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove(int))! You want to call [`list.remove((Integer)i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: *"the solution is to define the bean with scope request"* ... That really depends on the logic of your application. Usually any Util classes are not instantiated at all as they should not contain any state. If your does have state, then it depends. If the state is bound to a single request, sure, your solution is fine. If it is not, no. Welcome to software architecture :)